# Scroll view jumps to top when I add view at top

Tags: java, android

Im designing a chat app. When I scroll to top and reach the end I want to load more previous messages, the problem is when I add view at the top (at the same user already reached top), the scroll view jumps to top.

I quickly came up with solution that works, but looks bad because you can see for a milisecond how it jumps and I need to do it the way user won't notice.

My buggy solution (jump is visible in 1 frame):

```
int beforeHeight = messagesLinearLayout.getBottom();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
      messagesLinearLayout.addView(view, 0);
}

messagesLinearLayout.requestLayout();
messagesLinearLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int afterHeight = messagesLinearLayout.getBottom() - beforeHeight;
        messagesScrollView.scrollTo(0, afterHeight);
    }
});
```

Layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/messagesScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-15dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messagesLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true" />
</ScrollView>
```

Is there any way to make it not noticable? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: What I did to solve this problem was reversing the listview, or recyclerview. Then when adding an element you will stay at the same position and start from the bottom.

I don't recommend using scrollview or linearlayout for the job unless its a custom made view...
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: @DrBrad Thanks for your reply :). Is there any way to reverse scroll view?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I would look into recyclerview. It would serve everything your looking for for a chat system.

Comment: @DrBrad Thank you! It's much better and by default works as excepted! :D

Comment: Awesome, I'll write it as an answer if you'd like :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a recycler view instead of a scrollview with a linear layout. It will run much faster as it recycles used layouts/views for the next view insuring there are never more than lets say 10 views even if there are 1000 items.

Some examples on how to use recylcer view can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Another option I would recommend is the default ListView, works pretty nicely as well.